# uib-datepicker-popup calendar with null/NaN if input initially null

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use UI Bootstrap 1.3.2, Bootstrap 3.3.6 and Angularjs 1.5.5, but I'm having a problem with uib-datepicker-popup. If the value of the corresponding input field is null/not set, the calendar shows undefined date fields (null, NaN):

[image]

Code of input field:

```
<input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" datepicker-options="datepickerOptions" ng-model="mydto.teilnahmebis" />
```

The initDate option is ignored - code from controller:

```
$scope.datepickerOptions = {
                    minDate : new Date( '2010-01-01' ),
                    initDate : new Date() 
                };
```

The popup works if the input field already has a value. But normally that's not the case. Any idea, how to resolve this issue? Thanks for an answer.

Comment: you can assign your model `mydto.teilnahmebis` to a current date with your specified format.

Comment: This doesn't work because the model - which is transmitted to database after save() operation - shouldn't ever have  a value. Sometimes it needs to be null. Only the calendar should be initialized.

Comment: Yeah it should be null and its working like that. Its working properly. You might have done something wrong. Did you checked your console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, your ng-model variables is setting with a `invalid date` data...
check if you are overwriting your default value and set it as `null`

Comment: Yes, it's true, the date is "invalid date". I solved by coding:

    if ( $scope.mydto.teilnahmebis != null ) {
                        $scope.mydto.teilnahmebis = moment( $scope.mydto.teilnahmebis, 'DD.MM.YYYY' ).toDate();
                    }

Comment: Hint: If the ng-model is not null and is a (valid) date, I have to transform the delivered String date to a javascript Date, otherwise I ran in other problems with uib-datepicker-popup. If I convert a null String/date to a Date, I get - of course - an invalid date. Therefore I need the if-clause.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might have done something wrong.
I have created a `plunker` code for you, and its working as it should be.
You can go through it.
https://plnkr.co/edit/Yz2shW?p=preview